# Perl - How to substitute non matching words with none

Tags: regex, perl

I want to replace non matching words in a string with none using perl

```
$variable = "dx_app1_admin-101-102-prod;dx_app1_read-101-102-prod;dx_app2_admin-101-102-prod;dx_app2_admin-101-102-read;dx_app3_admin-101-102-prod;dx_app3_read-101-102-prod;";

$variable =~ s/?!(dx_app1_admin-101-102-prod;|dx_app1_read-101-102-prod;)//g;

print $variable;
```

Expected OutPut :

```
dx_app1_admin-101-102-prod;dx_app1_read-101-102-prod;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace all word characters after the negative lookahead matches:

```
$variable =~ s/\b(?!(car|truck|airplane);)\w+;//g;
```

Or, to only use semicolons as delimiters (rather than word boundaries):

```
$variable =~ s/((?<=;)|^)(?!(dx_app1_admin-101-102-prod|dx_app1_read-101-102-prod);)[^;]+;//g;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. But I really don't know what i need to remove, i know what to keep only.

Comment: @venkataprasad The code in my answer gives the expected output in your question. Is that not what you want?

Comment: I am very sorry for the confusion...i have edited my question ...

Comment: @venkataprasad I've updated my answer. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tcs7CoAwEEXR3lVEsVAsUlk9xI3YTCRIMIRh/DXi1mMQFLntuWzFtzGWO4kj463qVEHM3sJQSGEkwSrbOIOcsKdgUSDLfsOlFj2Yqs@rZM/Hnq@tUQ9HA62n9LC4sKrvRIw3)

Comment: Thank you, This worked like a charm. however i tried to use your same logic in my real time example, but it's some how not working...I have updated my question with my real data....Thanks again for your help!!!

Comment: @venkataprasad Updated: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@lLLEoMzEpJ1XBVkEppSI@saDAMD4xJTczT9fQwBCIjXQLivJTrGFSRamJKdhkjHBrQpcCGQGVMsatyxiLVUrWXFxIDq5TKNbX0LC3sbXWrAFRcZqaGvaKGrh9UYPTF5rWmtFx1rHa1vr66UBLCooy80oU4FZZ//8PAA)

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
my $variable = "dx_app1_admin-101-102-prod;dx_app1_read-101-102-prod;dx_app2_admin-101-102-prod;dx_app2_admin-101-102-read;dx_app3_admin-101-102-prod;dx_app3_read-101-102-prod;";
$variable = join ";", grep { /^dx_app1_(?:admin|read)/ } split /;/, $variable;
say $variable;
```

##### Output

```
dx_app1_admin-101-102-prod;dx_app1_read-101-102-prod
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use a regex.

```perl
my %keep = map { $_ => 1 } qw(
   dx_app1_admin-101-102-prod
   dx_app1_read-101-102-prod
);

say join ";", grep $keep{ $_ }, split /;/, $variable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of SKIP FAIL for what you don't want to match, and then match what you do want and replace with an empty string:

```
\bdx_app1_(?:read|admin)-101-102-prod;(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[^\s;]+;
```

**Explanation**

- `\bdx_app1_(?:read|admin)-101-102-prod;` Match either `dx_app1_admin-101-102-prod;` or `dx_app1_read-101-102-prod;` preceded by a word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` Skip the match
- `|` Or
- `[^\s;]+;` Match 1+ chars other than `;` or a whitespace char followed by matching `;`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xNb6Nz/1) and a [perl demo](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@lLLEoMzEpJ1XBVkEppSI@saDAMD4xJTczT9fQwBCIjXQLivJTrGFSRamJKdhkjHBrQpcCGQGVMsatyxiLVUrWXEjurVMo1o9JgjlMw94KpKEGbKAmqj4NrWBvzwBNDS03R08fzZrouJhi61hta339dGsuroKizLwSBbi51v//AwA).

```
$variable = "dx_app1_admin-101-102-prod;dx_app1_read-101-102-prod;dx_app2_admin-101-102-prod;dx_app2_admin-101-102-read;dx_app3_admin-101-102-prod;dx_app3_read-101-102-prod;";
$variable =~ s/\bdx_app1_(?:read|admin)-101-102-prod;(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[^\s;]+;//g;

print $variable;
```

Output

```
dx_app1_admin-101-102-prod;dx_app1_read-101-102-prod;
```